# Vectors Question?

Tags: calculus, vectors

A circle can be defined by an equation $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$. Find an equation of a circle that passes through $(-4,1)$, $(3,0)$, and $(5,4)$:

a. $x^2+y^2+2x-8y+5=0$

b. $x^2+y^2-2x-4=0$

c. $x^2+y^2-8y-9=0$

d. $x^2+y^2-8x+2y+5=0$

Not sure which one it is?

Comment: I think you entered the second answer choice with a typo. Also, please try to include what you've tried or some effort in your question; it'll make it more likely that someone will answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute in each point as $(x,y)$ into the general equation of the circle, obtaining 3 (simultaneous) equations in $a, b$ and $c$ that you must solve.

e.g. since $(-4,1)$ lies on the circle, we know that $(x,y)=(-4,1)$ satisfies $x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0$.

i.e. $(-4)^2+1^2+a(-4)+b(1)+c=0$.

Tidying this up, we get: $-4a+b+c+17=0 \tag{1}$

Using the other two points, and doing the same think I've just done, we obtain two more equations:

$ 3a+c+9=0\tag{2}$

$ 5a+4b+c+41=0\tag{3}$

Now, solve equations $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ (simultaneously) for $a, b$ and $c$ and you will have your equation.

> You should find that $a=0, b=-8, c=-9$.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation of the circle as follow: 
$$
x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0\Leftrightarrow (x+x_0)^2+(y+y_0)^2=r^2.
$$
$x_0=\dfrac{a}{2}$, $y_0=\dfrac{b}{2}$, and $r^2=\dfrac{a^2+b^2-4c}{4}$. Of course, $a^2+b^2-4c\geqslant0$ must holds.

Replace your points $(x, y)$ and you will see if it satisfies the circle's equation or not.